# Tell the publisher write message to disk in case of queue (rabbit server) unavailable

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have a publisher that sends throught radio link packets to he rabbitmq server queue. 
Is posible to make the client (publisher) store messages to disk before send them in case of the server stays unavailable during 4hours for example?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but only on application level on top of AMQP client library you use. Optionally, your client library may have some scheduling mechanism to do what you want.